# using boost::bind with a map

Tags: boost, bind, stdmap

```
    bool takeInt(int a,int b) 
    {
      cout << a << " " << b << endl;   return true;
    } 

    int main()
    { 
      map<int,int> m;
      m.insert(make_pair(1,2));
      m.insert(make_pair(2,5));
      m.insert(make_pair(4,8));
      m.insert(make_pair(5,6));
for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),boost::bind(&takeInt,42,boost::bind(&pair<int,int>::first,_1)));
     return 0;
    }
```

I want an output of

```
42 1
42 2
42 4
42 5
```

Fails compilation with loong errors. 
Any clue on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `map<T, U>::value_type` is `pair<const T, U>`. Use this:

```
for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),
         boost::bind(&takeInt, 42, boost::bind(&pair<const int,int>::first,_1)));
                                                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: out of curiosity: where did find the definition of the map::value_type ? 
@myself: just looked up definition on cpp.com and it cleary says value_type : 'pair<const Key,T>'

Comment: @CarstenGreiner In this case I was pretty sure, otherwise I look it up in the standard (usually the draft N3337 http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or the library implementation itself.

Comment: From this, I learn to always use the typedef unless its not possible. `boost::bind(&Map::value_type::first,_1)`

Comment: @balki Excellent conclusion. Your code also became considerably more robust to change. Essentially, every time you specify template parameters manually to access a nested type, you are making it harder to change your code.